# Click button in Full Calendar popover is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fullcalendar

I've created a click button on popover of events in FullCalendar to perform some xyz action . But the function ("detailcheck") created is not working . It would be helpfull If someone can guide me through the issue in below mentioned code snippet?

[Full Calendar Popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJnfL.png)

```
$scope.uiConfig = { 

    calendar: {
        name : 'calender1',
        height: 600,
        editable: true,
        header: {
            left: 'title',
            center: '',
            right: 'today prev,next'
        },
        eventClick: $scope.alertOnEventClick,
        eventMouseover: function () { $scope.checked = true; },
        eventMouseout: function () { $scope.checked = false; },
        eventDrop: $scope.alertOnDrop,
        //eventResize: $scope.alertOnResize,
        eventRender: function (event, element) {
            var chk = $(event.target).css('display', 'block');
            element.popover({
                trigger: "click",
                html: true,
                animation: true,
                content: '<div ng-show="checked"><button class="btn btn-danger pop" ng-click="detailcheck(event)">abc</button><b>Inicio</b>:' + event.start + "<b>Fin</b>:" + event.end + "</div>",
            })
        },
        firstDay: 1,
        viewRender : function (view, element) {
            $scope.calendarrangestart = view.start._d;
            $scope.calendarrangeend = view.end._d;  
        }
    }
};
$scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];
$scope.detailcheck = function (event) {
    console.log("hi");
}
```

Comment: I don't know Angular at all but I would guess it may not bind events to arbitrary HTML which is inserted dynamically from a string. I would guess that you probably need to tell Angular explicitly to notice that `ng-click` declaration and wire up the event. That's just my assumption, I don't know if it's correct, or how you go about notifying Angular that you want it to handle this event, but it seems logical that it would be necessary, for code you've added in this way.

Comment: i think you should use it like this `eventClick: function(){$scope.alertOnEventClick},` same for the eventDrop

Comment: and i guess it needs brackets too `$scope.alertOnEventClick() `

Comment: oh i see. you're giving it a ng-click in the event render function. have you tried using compile? `$compile(element)($scope)`inside the render function?

Comment: John , $scope.alertOnEventClick is used for displaying some other information when i click on an event in calendar and it works fine.My problem is with the click button present  in popup.

Comment: Okay got that. So i would try it with the $compile. If you're using scope inside the elements they need to be compiled.

Comment: check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24969445/how-to-add-angular-directive-to-full-calendar-event)

Comment: I tried but still not resolved.

Comment: can you provide a codepen ?

Comment: `ng-click="detailcheck(event)` is this the click event or the calendar event?

Comment: it is a click event

Comment: maybe try [$event](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

###Fixed the issue ,not an angular solution but applying a bit jquery resolved my issue ###

```
 {   calendar: {
    name : 'calender1',
    height: 600,
    editable: true,
    header: {
        left: 'title',
        center: '',
        right: 'today prev,next'
    },
    eventClick: $scope.alertOnEventClick,
    eventMouseover: function () { $scope.checked = true; },
    eventMouseout: function () { $scope.checked = false; },
    eventDrop: $scope.alertOnDrop,
    //eventResize: $scope.alertOnResize,
    eventRender: function (event, element) {
        var chk = $(event.target).css('display', 'block');
        element.popover({
            trigger: "click",
            html: true,
            animation: true,
            content: '<div ng-show="checked"><button id="object_" class="btn btn-danger pop">abc</button><b>Inicio</b>:' + event.start + "<b>Fin</b>:" + event.end + "</div>",
        });
            $('.fc-content-skeleton').on('click', '#object_', function () {
                $scope.scop = true;
                console.log("abcs");
                console.log($scope.scop);
            });
    },
    firstDay: 1,
    viewRender : function (view, element) {
        $scope.calendarrangestart = view.start._d;
        $scope.calendarrangeend = view.end._d;  
    }
}};
$scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];
```